# Symfony2 / Doctrine / Mapping Converter / Relationship / PK Strange Behavior

Tags: symfony, doctrine, primary-key, converters, relationship

After searching for a whole while i decided to show you my problem with the mapping converter implementation in Symfony2. First, i show you my setup:

The user tables having a relationship:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `event_manager`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `event_manager`.`user` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event_manager`.`user` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `salt` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `logged_in` TINYINT(1) NULL ,
  `status` ENUM('active', 'inactive', 'deleted') NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_user_data1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
    REFERENCES `event_manager`.`user_data` (`user_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `event_manager`.`user_data`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `event_manager`.`user_data` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event_manager`.`user_data` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `image_id` INT NULL ,
  `gender` ENUM('male','female') NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `zip` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `city` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `phone_private` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `phone_mobile` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `phone_work` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `user_datacol` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_data_image1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`image_id` )
    REFERENCES `event_manager`.`image` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_user_data_image1_idx` ON `event_manager`.`user_data` (`image_id` ASC) ;
```

With that on my DB, i use the doctrine converter with this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/path-to-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine --from-database --force --filter=User
```

Then i get this result on the user YAML:

```
User:
  type: entity
  table: user
  fields:
      email:
          type: string
          length: 255
          fixed: false
          nullable: true
      salt:
          type: string
          length: 255
          fixed: false
          nullable: true
      password:
          type: string
          length: 255
          fixed: false
          nullable: true
      loggedIn:
          type: boolean
          nullable: true
          column: logged_in
      status:
          type: string
          length: null
          fixed: false
          nullable: true
  manyToMany:
      userGroup:
          targetEntity: UserGroup
          cascade: {  }
          mappedBy: null
          inversedBy: user
          joinTable:
              name: user_has_user_group
              joinColumns:
                  -
                      name: user_id
                      referencedColumnName: id
              inverseJoinColumns:
                  -
                      name: user_group_id
                      referencedColumnName: id
          orderBy: null
  oneToOne:
      id:
          targetEntity: UserData
          cascade: {  }
          mappedBy: null
          inversedBy: null
          joinColumns:
              id:
                  referencedColumnName: user_id
          orphanRemoval: false
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

As you can see, doctrine removes the "id" column as primary key and uses it instead as the name for the relationship which brings me finally to entity methods like this:

```
/**
 * Set id
 *
 * @param \Parella\EventManagerBundle\Entity\UserData $id
 * @return User
 */
public function setId(\Parella\EventManagerBundle\Entity\UserData $id = null)
{
    $this->id = $id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return \Parella\EventManagerBundle\Entity\UserData 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

This is of course totally not what i want, and i have often to create many entites at once from the database, so manually fixing this is not really an option. Unfortunately i have no idea if i'm causing the problem or doctrine. Do i miss something?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Interesting.  Doctrine probably does not support a single column being both primary id as well as participating in an owning relation.  Even if it did I think it might a bit iffy trying to keep ids in sync.  Add a user_data_id column to user and put the relation on it.  And added int is a small prices to pay especially if you end up with additional relations.  If you really want to keep user_data_id in sync then you can.

Answer (score 0):

Copied my comment to here because I confirmed the actual problem.

Doctrine does not support a single column being both primary id as well as participating in an owning relation. Think about it.  What should $user->getId() return?  The id or $userData?

Add a user_data_id column to user and put the relation on it.

And I would just edit the yml files and then use doctrine:schema:drop/update to generate the tables.  Let Doctrine do things it's way unless you really need to maintain control.

Comment: I also did some investigation on my self and placed the foreign key on the user_data table side to check it out. In this case the same happens, the primary key inside the yaml is gone but(!) the relation is correctly named as "user" and not "id" (guess it's because of the user_id prefix which got detected by doctrine). On the user_data side, it wouldn't be that bad that the primary key is missing since its an one-to-one relation and there will never be a user_data row without a user, but doctrine builds the relation methods on the "wrong" entity. I'll stick with your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that doctrine:mapping:convert only claims to be able to handle about 80% or so of the use cases.  As you said, just adjust the yaml file and then recreate the database from using doctrine.